# Javascript Hash Prototype to C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a javascript string.prototype that creates a hash for a string.
JS:

```
    String.prototype.hashCode = function () {
        var hash = 5381, i = this.length
        while (i)
            hash = (hash * 33) ^ this.charCodeAt(--i)
        return hash >>> 0;
    }
```

I need to recreate this hash in C# for another application that uses the same database. Below is what I have so far...

```
    public string hashCode(string password)
    {
        var hash = 5381;
        int i;
        string newHash = "";
        int index = password.Length;
        for (i = 0; i > index; i++)
            hash = (hash * 33) ^ (char)password[--index];
        hash = (int)((uint)index >> 0);
        newHash += hash;
        return newHash;
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hash codes may differ from version to version, so using them for anything else than speedy comparisons may lead to problems later on. That being said, you may want to write some unit tests. I'd start with verifying that Java uses the same encoding for strings.

Comment: Why are you converting a hash to a string? It's normally a number (and is a number in your JS code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was few mistake with the code.

```
public string hashCode(string password)
{
     int hash = 5381;
     int i = password.Length;

     while(i > 0)
          hash = (hash * 33) ^ (char)password[--i];
     hash = (int)((uint)i >> 0);
     return hash.ToString();
 }
```